# Parse Json with com.fasterxml.jackson instead of org.json

Tags: java, json, parsing, jackson

I was wondering if it is possible to do this exact operation but with the jackson library.

```
String repo = response.toString();
JSONObject json = new JSONObject (repo);
String nameOfUser = json.getJSONObject(facebookID).getString("name");
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Something like:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); // reuse, usually static final
JsonNode ob = mapper.readTree(response.toString()); // or from File, URL, InputStream, Reader
String nameOfUser = ob.path(facebookID).path("name").asText();
// note: '.get()' also works, but returns nulls, 'path()' safer
```

although even more convenient access is often done using JSON Pointer expressions, like:

```
String name = ob.at("/person/id").asText();
```

but I assume `facebookID` is an id from some other source.

UPDATE: as per comment below, structure you want may actually be POJO like:

```
public class Response {
  public User facebookID;
}
public class User {
   public String id;
   public String email;
   public String first_name;
   // ... and so forth: fields and/or getter+setter
}
```

and then you can bind directly into class like so:

```
Response resp = mapper.readValue(response.toString(), Response.class);
String name = resp.facebookID.name;
```

So there's more than one way to do it with Jackson.

Comment: The returned response string looks like this 
`{"facebookID":{"id":"facebookID","email":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","first_name":"Marcus","gender":"male","last_name":"Bengtsson","link":"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/app_scoped_user_id\/xxxxxxxxxxx\/","locale":"sv_SE","middle_name":"Peter","name":"Marcus Rufus Bengtsson"}}`
But yeah, thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for. Just recently getting into jackson. I don't know why, but I feel like json is easier to understand...

Comment: why not create java value object that models this json message? That way you can simply do valuObject.getXXXX().

Comment: @user3191617 org.json is much smaller package so perhaps it is easier to "know it all" making it seem simpler. Jackson has bigger API due to bigger feature set and it can take a while to learn enough to feel comfortable.